# How are engines numbered on Starship and Super Heavy?

Tags: spacex-starship, terminology

I was watching [this video](https://youtu.be/qQwLg84NNXs) summarizing Elon Musk's recent remarks on the orbital test flight, and they mention specific engines. But unless a named engine shuts down and is shown on the small display in the SpaceX feed replay, I don't know where a specific engine is.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you watch [SpaceX's live stream](https://youtu.be/-1wcilQ58hI) of the Integrated Flight Test, you will notice that they helpfully painted the engine numbers onto the inside of the engine bells of all of the engines:

You can see that the engines are numbered in concentric rings, clockwise, always starting in the same corner:

- The inner circle of three Raptor Center engines is numbered E1–E3.
- The middle ring of ten Raptor Center engines is numbered E4–E13.
- The outer ring of twenty Raptor Boost engines is numbered E14–E33.

Unfortunately, it is not possible to see on that shot what the orientation of the camera is. If I had to guess, engines E1, E4, and E14 are directly on the Z-axis of the vehicle, i.e. perfectly leeward (facing the tower) or perfectly windward (opposite the tower).

Engines E17–E20, which had their shielding blown off at T+20s, are in the top left corner of the frame. Engine E6, which lost communication to the vehicle is also in that same corner.

Comment: I've been using [this image stack](https://imgur.com/a/iMCimr1/) from [this reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/spacex/comments/12t04pd/figuring_out_which_boosters_failed_to_ignitee3/jh1985g/), which also starts with the under-Starship camera angle from the test flight.  If you compare it to [the tower angle SpaceX released](https://twitter.com/SpaceX/status/1649172873494556679) you can see which center engine corresponds to the toward-tower side by scrubbing to around 23s to observe which center engine is out.  I believe your E1-E4-E14 guess is correct based on that.

Comment: Don't you think that E1 feels so proud? They can tell their grandchildren "We were 33 engines, and I was chosen to be no. 1."

Comment: Or, at second thought, E1 can tell it to the bottom dwellers in the Gulf of Mexico ;-).